# Passing parameter to css :not selector

Tags: javascript, css, selector

I have a function to hide all divs on the page except one div.

```
// hide all div exceept div1
function hideAllExcept()
{
  $('div:not(#div1)').slideUp(800);
}
```

or

```
// hide all div exceept 'thisdiv' 
function hideAllExcept()
{
  $('div:not("#div1")').slideUp(800);
}
```

The above works fine (difference is first function doesn't have "" around #div1). However, I would like to pass a parameter in the hideAllExcept function to dynamically specify which div to not hide. So I changed the function to:

```
// hide all div exceept 'thisdiv' 
function hideAllExcept(thisdiv)
{
  $('div:not(thisdiv)').slideUp(800);
}
```

if i call the function using: `hideAllExcept('#div1')` or `hideAllExcept("#div1")` it doesn't work. It seems that $('div:not(thisdiv)') still selects all divs, it doesn't exclude thisdiv.

Any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
function hideAllExcept(thisdiv) {
  $('div:not('+thisdiv+')').slideUp(800);
}
```

Comment: thanks all, all answers are pretty similar so have to choose the first answer. btw, is this trick documented anywhere? I googled it before posting on SO but had no luck finding it anywhere.

Comment: It's not really a trick, but JavaScript string concatenation. You're dynamically building the selector.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div').not(thisdiv).slideUp(800);
```

Comment: I think you mean `$('div').not(thisdiv).slideUp(800);` But I like this better than the others. It will allow passing an element reference, rather than just a string.

Comment: dang though I got the fix in before anyone noticed, but yes, the .not() function is better since it can take the full variety of inputs

Comment: Did I just read that wrong? I could have sworn that said `filter`, but I don't see an edit.... Weird.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not just going crazy. Good :)

Comment: I deleted it as soon as I noticed to double check it, edited in then undeleted it, which apparently doesn't trigger an edit flag

Comment: This is slower than using the `:not(...)`, since you would select all `DIV` elements and then filter them with the `.not(...)` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divid='div:not('+thisdiv+')';
$(divid).slideUp(800);
```